# Как перечитать property файл, во время выполнения программы в Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте. Я пишу программу используя технологии Spring + Maven.
Мне нужно, чтобы у конечного пользователя была возможность *подредактировать app.properties  файл, который лежит в папке resources моего проекта, не останавливая программу.* Программа периодически должна проверять этот файл на предмет изменений.

И с этим у меня возникли трудности. Такой вариант **не** работает:

```
@Component
public class ProgrammProperties {

    @Value("${value}")
    private String value;
}
```

Так же **не** работает этот вариант:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
class Test {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public Object getValue(String name) {
        return environment.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

и **не** работает этот вариант:

```
class PropertyLoader {
    private Properties prop = new Properties();
    private InputStream inputStream;

    private Object getProp(String name) {
        Object  ans = null;
        try {           
            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties");
            prop.load(inputStream);
            ans = prop.getProperty( name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("не удалось найти файл");
            log.error(e);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

А вот этот вариант **работает**:

```
class PropertyLoader {
 private Properties prop = new Properties();
    private InputStream inputStream;

    private Object getProp(String name) {
        Object  ans = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("app.properties");
            prop.load(inputStream);
            ans = prop.getProperty( name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("не удалось найти файл");
            log.error(e);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Но,с этим вариантом я получаю досадный велосипед, у меня получается два конфигурационных файла:

1. конфигурационый файл мавена, который лежит в папке ресурсов проекта, упакован внутри .war архива. И его я не могу его менять во время выполнения программы , чтобы она это увидела.
2. свой конфигурационный файл, который надо подкладывать самостоятельно в папку веб контейнера (в моем случае это apache/tomcat/bin).

Могу я обойтись для этой задачи одним конфигурационным файлом (мавеновским) ?

Comment: нет. лучше положить файл рядом, читать  и менять. а если файл большой, то лучше БД иметь. также spring умеет сам читать проперти файлы и подставлять значение. тогда вам loader() не нужен будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо конфиг файл хранить отдельно, скажем `./config/app.properties`
Обновить данные каждые N секунд

```
public static final Properties PROPS = new Properties();

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)  // every 5 sec
private void refreshProps() {
    Path path = Paths.get("./config/app.properties");
    try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
        PROPS.load(reader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(path.toAbsolutePath().toString() + " load exception", e);
    }
}
```

И не забудьте `@EnableScheduling`